# How to deploy Rails Application that uses Gulp to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, heroku, gulp

I am building an app follow [this tutorial](http://www.angularonrails.com/how-to-wire-up-ruby-on-rails-and-angularjs-as-a-single-page-application-gulp-version/)

Basically, it is a rails app that is separate from the front-end.

I am using gulp to compile everything and utilizing a Gulp proxy to talk to the back end via the /api path. Gulp compiles all the front-end code to a single directory.

I am struggling to understand how to deploy an app like this to Heroku and have the front-end part of the app talk to the rails backend.

Does anyone have any experience deploying an app like this to Heroku?

Comment: You may want to look at having a background worker dyno run your Rails app + your public-facing web dyno running Gulp. See this for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing - you can specify the different dynos in your Procfile.

Answer (score 2):

I published a blog post about this. It's called ["Angular on Rails Deployed to Heroku Using Gulp"](http://grantgeorge.io/angular-on-rails-deployed-to-heroku-using-gulp/)

1. Configure multiple buildpacks, setting ruby and node. [See the Heroku official documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app).
2. Configure gulp to build in the ./public directory at the root of the app.
3. Configure an npm postinstall script that builds your app

Have fun!

Comment: I'm unable to view the blog.

Comment: @gnerkus for some reason the post came down. I have the same information captured in this repo: https://github.com/grantgeorge/railsAngularTutorial

Comment: Thank you. I've gone through the repo and found it useful.

Comment: Glad to hear. Ping me if I can help out further!